# How to switch different table throgh the combobox without adding additional column

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I have a database named `appmondb` and I want to use the combobox to switch tables. If I select the ids table first, it is no problem, but if I select the accounts table next, the fields of ids and accounts will appear at the same time.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        currentdt.Clear();//clear table 
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;

        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + comboBox1.Text;

        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, Connection.connMaster);

        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        adapter.Fill(currentdt);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = currentdt;
        totalPage = calculateTotalPages(currentdt);//update totalPage
}
```

[first I choose ids table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahZvM.png)

[after that, I select accounts table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLdyw.png)

I have something to say that it should be .fill() or the wording of dataset and datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Clear` on the `DataTable` removes all the rows but it doesn't remove the columns, so they are still there when you call `Fill` for the new query. You'll need to either create a new `DataTable` each time or else `Clear` the `Columns` collection as well.

I'm fairly certain that clearing the `DataSource` is not going to remove any columns from the grid either, so you're going to have to `Clear` the `Columns` collection of the grid too. Like so:

```cs
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
currentdt.Clear();
currentdt.Columns.Clear();
```

Comment: I don't think it's feasible to clear columns one by one . I'm currently thinking about whether there is a way to dynamically add datatable or dataset

Comment: You don't need to clear anything one by one. You're already calling `Clear` on the `DataTable`. Just call `Clear` on the `Columns` property of the `DataTable` and the `Columns` property of the grid as well. See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks man its work for me ! appreciate